# AIR applications using HTML don't pick up alt and title tags to show tooltips

Tags: html, image, air

I'm building a HTML application to run in an Adobe AIR container, but the `alt` tag for the `img` element and the `title` tag for the `a` element don't show a tooltip like a browser would.

Is there anyway to enable this, or display it another way?

Comment: You should not be using the alt attribute for tooltips! All elements support title attribute, and that is the correct one to use in all cases. (Images should have an ALTernative text attribute for the benefit of clients that cannot see what the images contain).

Comment: +1 This is *the* answer, I wish I could give you some real points.

Comment: First things first: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/its_alt_attribute_not_alt_tag/

Comment: This was [confirmed as a bug](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/750509) by Adobe back in 2010... and yet it's still b0rked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AIR you're guaranteed that Javascript will be enabled, so just throw in a Javascript tooltip that uses the title/alt attributes.