# Are Flex HTML Component <a> Tooltips Disabled?

Tags: html, apache-flex, air

I'm working on an AIR application in Flex using the HTML component.

The page that loads inside the component has a few "a" tags that all have titles for tooltips.

However, they don't show up inside the component at all, but in a regular browser they show up just fine.

It's based on WebKit, so I just assumed everything would work great in there.

Does anyone know how to get these enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3277151) from a couple years ago that mentions the non-functioning of the title attribute inside of AIR as a known bug. I couldn't find the mentioned bug inside Adobe's bug reporting system ([here](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa)).

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854182/air-applications-using-html-dont-pick-up-alt-and-title-tags) on StackOverflow. The only suggestion was to use Javascript to emulate the title attribute tooltip. That might be worth exploring.